# Error when uploading a file to the media library

Tags: media-library

I'm getting the following message when uploading a file to the Media Library:

```
The file "xxxx.jpg" is too big to be uploaded.
The maximum size of a file that can be uploaded is -205,824 bytes.
```

I've tried to max every setting on the web.config, but I have the same result:
https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2012/04/20/sitecore-media-library-upload-errors/

What strikes me is where is that negative value coming from?

**EDIT**

I've decompiled the dll where this error is being thrown:
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.FlashUpload.Simple.

The error is being thrown here:

```
long databaseUploadSize = Settings.Upload.MaximumDatabaseUploadSize;
if ((long) num > databaseUploadSize)
{
    string text = Translate.Text("The file \"{0}\" is too big to be uploaded.\n\nThe maximum size of a file that can be uploaded is {1}.", (object) filename, (object) MainUtil.FormatSize(databaseUploadSize));
    this.WarningMessage = text;
    SheerResponse.Alert(text);
}
```

Apparently there is something wrong when Sitecore tries to read the Media settings. I've tried to modify them but no luck. It seems they are being read from somewhere else or it is not being able to read them from the config file.

databaseUploadSize has a negative number.

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: It happens with any file size, so the size of the file being uploaded seems unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Can you check this setting : <setting name="Media.MaxSizeInMemory" value="60MB" />

Comment: It has the default value: <setting name="Media.MaxSizeInMemory" value="40MB" />

Comment: check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` for this setting value. maybe there is a patch file which changes the value?

Comment: @matap Please create an answer of your solution and mark it as answered afterwards. This makes it clear to everyone that a solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.
httpRuntime maxRequestLength="**2147483647**"

That value should be set on Kb and not bytes, and Sitecore is doing the following calculation:

```
  public static long EffectiveMaxRequestLengthBytes
  {
    get
    {
      return (long) ((Settings.Runtime.MaxRequestLength - 200) * 1024);
    }
  }
```

And then:

```
  public static long MaximumDatabaseUploadSize
  {
    get
    {
      return Math.Min(Settings.Media.MaxSizeInDatabase, Settings.Runtime.EffectiveMaxRequestLengthBytes);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just curious .. what is the significance of -200 in that calculation.. Understanding multiplication by 1024 is quite straight forward but I am having a hard time understanding why 200 is subtracted? Is it countering for header / footer of the packet or something?

Comment: Yeah, those magic numbers are hard to guess. I also couldn't figure out why -200. Also, they should have cast the variable to long and not the operation result.

Comment: Yes, anyways glad you found the answer :)